# Spring xml-less config: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-mapping

We have a Spring MVC app with controllers:

`@Controller("/app")`

`@Controller("/app/page1")`

`@Controller("/app/page2")`

And we have AppInitializer:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();

    DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet1", servlet);
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/app/*");
  }

  private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    ... prepare app context
  }
}
```

When running this app, we are able to access

http://localhost:8080/app

But

http://localhost:8080/app/page1 results in error

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/page1] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet1'

and

http://localhost:8080/app/page2 results in error

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/page2] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet1'

We can fix this by adding strict mapping to DispatcherServlet like this

```
DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet1", servlet);
dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
dispatcher.addMapping("/app", "/app/page1", "/app/page2");
```

and all pages work fine:

http://localhost:8080/app

http://localhost:8080/app/page1

http://localhost:8080/app/page2

But the problem is that we need to add mapping to DispatcherServlet every time we add new page. For example to add page 3 we would need to create Controller

`@Controller("/app/page3")`

and

add dispatcher servlet mapping  `dispatcher.addMapping("/app", "/app/page1", "/app/page2", **"/app/page3"**);`

We would really like to avoid this last step.

`dispatcher.addMapping("/app/*");` would be ideal, but as I mentioned above it is not working.

Any idea what we missing?

Comment: Remove `/app` from the controller mappings. It is the mapping INSIDE the dispatcher servlet NOT the full URI.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks mate, that worked like a charm. Exactly what we wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the mapping like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app/products")
public class ProductController implements Serializable {...}
```

Comment: How is it different from


`@Controller("/app/products")`

`public class ProductController implements Serializable {...}`

Comment: @user606621 `@Controller("/app/products")` means you're creating a bean as controller with name "/app/products"